# create a trigger for purge or discard partition event in informix ids12

Tags: informix

I defined a "rolling window" for partition's table with "any discard" so the partition that includ this condition   automatically is  purged or discard in 00:45'am .

I have a problem with  replication for this table because the table mode is changed to alter mode after purging.

How can i prevent it ?

Is there any solution for this case and if no how can i create a trigger for change table mode after purge event?

Comment: What you means with "table mode" , you change the table to `RAW`mode? Please, edit your question and include the commands utilized and the errors occurred.

Comment: Hi ,NO i didnt chang table mode to alter , i think after authomatic discard in 00:45 h it changes to alter mode. tanx